# Restrict the number of time an application is installed on machine

Tags: c#, windows, security, ms-office, producer-consumer

How does a big key product like those of MSOffices restrict their buyers/users by either the number of its installation times or the number of its installed machines ? 
For one software CD, the product are installed and useable via for example 3 licenses, this is activated via provided keys. Why can't I user the same key on 3 machines that are not interconnected ?
For one software CD, the product is sometimes installable only on one machine (no key reference), it will display an error message if I try to install it on another. (the CD isn't rewritable "ekk")

Answer (score 3):

Because the software from Micrsoft requires "activation". In this procedure the software is sending a footprint of the machine together with the software key it is installed on to Microsoft's licence server. In the database of that licence server Microsoft keeps those footprints and a counter, so they can ensure their software isn't activated more often then paid for.